# Bidirectional conversion between two types

Tags: scala

I have two classes

```
case class A (field1: String, field2: Int)

class B {var myField1: String, var myField2: String}
```

(In fact there are lots of field but I use only 2 for example)

And I need to convert from `A` to `B` and back.
Currently I have two methods with lots of assignment.

Is there a way to describe mapping between those fields once?
I looked to `Lens` but didn't find solution to this problem yet.

It looks like very common situation, so I believe there is standard solution.

Comment: what about inheritance??

Comment: I can't change field names and types sometime different. I don't see how inheritance can help.

Comment: so you have 2 similar classes, but not the same

Comment: Yes. They used to interact with two different subsystem.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for an [Isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism).

[Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle) provides these:

```
val AtoB = Iso[A, B]((a: A) => new B(a.field1, p.field2))((B: B) => A(p.myField1, b.myField2))

val myB:B = AtoB.get(A("one", 1))

val myA:A = AtoB.reverseGet(myB)
```

There are more examples in the [monocle docs](https://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle//tut/iso.html)

Comment: It is look like solution I search for, but we use `maven` and `Monocle` available on `sbt` only.

Comment: sbt is just the build tool. It's hosted at maven central, you can add the dependency as normal

Comment: this page http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.julien-truffaut/monocle-core_2.11/1.2.0 will show the maven snippet to add

Comment: I reread you answer and found that this is not what I want. Your solution force me to write mapping between fields twice: once in constructor of `A` and another time in constructor of `B`. I'm already have this solution. I want to specify mapping only once.

Comment: I've actually just re-read your question ;) and seen that you've got different types for the second field. This can't be an isomorphism because while all Ints can be Strings, not all Strings can be Ints. You might want to look at Prisms to do what you want, however you are likely to need to specify the translation both ways unless you adhere to other types of constraints. Have a look at the macros provided by monocle.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can ease the usage of the different classes  using `implicits` and `implicit classes`.

```
case class ExampleA (field1: String, field2: Int)
class ExampleB(var myField1: String, var myField2: String)

implicit def aToB(in: ExampleA) : ExampleB = new ExampleB(in.field1, in.field2.toString) 
implicit def bToA(in: ExampleB) : ExampleA = ExampleA(in.myField1, in.myField2.toInt)

def functionThatWorksWith_A_And_B[A <% ExampleA](in: A) : Int = in.field2
```

-

```
scala> functionThatWorksWith_A_And_B( new ExampleB("exampleB", "99"))
res5: Int = 99

scala> functionThatWorksWith_A_And_B(ExampleA("exampleA", 5))
res6: Int = 5
```